# How to get ascms.exe from ascmd.cs -.csproj and -.sln files?

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, ascmd

I have downloaded Samples for MS SQL Server 2005 and I don't know how to get an .exe file from files like ascmd.sln, ascmd.cs, ascmd.csproj. When I'm trying to launch an .sln file in Visual Studio there is an error like:

> The application for project C:\project_path\project_name is not installed

Do I need a C# compiler or something like that?

Answer (score 2):

yes, you will need to compile the .CS file.  The compilers are part of Visual Studio Express ([download](http://www.microsoft.com/express/download/)).  You'll want the C# Edition.

One you have it installed, you can run the command "csc ascmd.cs" to compile.  csc is located in %windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.5\csc.exe

Alternatively, you can compile from the IDE.  Just double click the .sln or .csproj file and the IDE will open.  CRTL+SHIFT+B compiles.  F5 runs.

Thev v3.5 will vary based on the version you install.